# Problems running Test::Unit with Guard on Rails 4.1.1 and Ruby 2.1.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, guard, minitest, testunit

I'm upgrading an app from Rails 3.2 using Ruby 2.0 to Rails 4.1 using Ruby 2.1.

Running our Test::Unit tests with `rake test` works perfectly fine, but running the tests with `guard` is a failure.

```
 15:30:14 - INFO - Guard::Test 2.0.5 is running, with Test::Unit 2.5.5!
 15:30:14 - INFO - Running all tests
 invalid option: --use-color

 minitest options:
 >    -h, --help                       Display this help.
 >    -s, --seed SEED                  Sets random seed
 >    -v, --verbose                    Verbose. Show progress processing files.
 >    -n, --name PATTERN               Filter run on /pattern/ or string.
 Known extensions: pride
 >    -p, --pride                      Pride. Show your testing pride!
```

It looks like Minitest is being used instead of Test::Unit and [this github issue](https://github.com/guard/guard-test/issues/54) confirmed that for me.

**We have no intention of using Minitest**, but we tried `guard-minitest`. It took care of the above issue. Now our tests run but they're all failing with:

```
 TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

I'm not sure if using `guard-minitest` is the solution. If it is, then I need help with the TypeError. But we are hoping to stick with Test::Unit.

[Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/naikipl/b15a65e4b538d60b1c58) of Gemfile.lock, test_helper.rb and Guardfile

---

There is no stack trace with the TypeError and we are getting it with every test, so I can't track it to one piece of code. This is what's happening in the logs.

```
(0.4ms)  ALTER TABLE "spatial_ref_sys" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "buildings" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "location_names" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "post_boxes" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "regions" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "street_number_matches" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "street_numbers" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "territorial_authorities" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "unit_matches" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "units" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "schema_migrations" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL
```

```
(0.2ms)  ALTER TABLE "spatial_ref_sys" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "buildings" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "location_names" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "post_boxes" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "regions" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "street_number_matches" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "street_numbers" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "territorial_authorities" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "unit_matches" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "units" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "schema_migrations" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL
```

Comment: A full stack trace and the relevant code which fails would help a lot

Comment: In rails 4 things like ActionController::TestCase are minitest. It may be possible to still use test::unit but you'll be fighting against the flow

Answer (score 0):

To get the stack trace, you probably have to set verbose mode in the test, e.g.

```
TESTOPTS="--verbose" bundle exec guard
```

or maybe as an option to `guard-test`:

```
guard :test, cli: '--verbose' do
```

or maybe it's:

```
guard :test, cli: '--debug' do
```

I'm not a test-unit/Minitest expert, but either the same option should work for Minitest, or maybe the environment variable:

```
VERBOSE=1 bundle exec guard
```

or maybe

```
DEBUG=1 bundle exec guard
```

or maybe

```
BACKTRACE=1 bundle exec guard
```